# Lock On Insert in Sql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, deadlock

I am using the following code to insert in database:

```
Employe emp1=new Employe ();
emp1.setId(12)
.getCurrentSession().saveorUpdate(emp1)
.getCurrentSession().flush()
Employe emp2=new Employe ();
emp2.setId(12)
entitymanger.merge(emp2)
entitymanger.flush()
```

and everything work fine however when I use the following one it makes a deadlock

```
Employe emp1=new Employe ();
emp1.setId(12)
.getCurrentSession().saveorUpdate(emp1)
Employe emp2=new Employe ();
emp2.setId(12)
entitymanger.merge(emp2)
entitymanger.flush()
.getCurrentSession().flush()
```

Why this led to a dead lock and not insert the records in first one then flush and insert in the second one. Note that it is the same Id.

Comment: Do you get an actual deadlock, or are you just getting a lock? Because they're different things. Deadlocks typically involve multiple tables, or rarely multiple indexes on the same table, getting locked in different orders and so unable to complete because multiple processes are waiting on one another to complete. e.g.: connection A wants to update Employee1 then Manager2, connection B wants to update Manager2 then Employee1, but they each hold locks on the specific records that the other wants to update. When SQL Server detects this it rolls back one of the transactions and errors.

Comment: I suspect you need to read up on Hibernate's `flush()` function and its behaviour around queuing DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE statements.

Comment: yes it is a lock and after investigation it seems only entitymanager.flush() lock the row until the commit and not like the session.